Update Storyboard Binding in Real TIme
I want to animate an object along a circle with a sinusoidal radius, where the amplitude and frequency can change.
I've managed to create the sinusoidal circle, and an object which follows its initial path. Additionally, as I change the amplitude of the circle it does change. However, the object's path does not update and I'm not sure how to make it do so.
The XAML:
<Grid>
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Stretch="Uniform" x:Name="MainPath" SizeChanged="MainPath_SizeChanged" Fill="Green" Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="ScaledAnimationPath">
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint}">
                        <PolyLineSegment Points="{Binding Points}"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
<Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Blue">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform"  />
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>

    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">

                    <!-- Animates the rectangle horizotally along the path. -->
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
        Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
        PathGeometry="{Binding ElementName=ScaledAnimationPath}"
        Source="X" 
        Duration="0:0:3"  />

                    <!-- Animates the rectangle vertically along the path. -->
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
        Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
        PathGeometry="{Binding ElementName=ScaledAnimationPath}"
        Source="Y"
        Duration="0:0:3"  />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>

(the SizeChanged event calls a method in the VM - done to scale the PolyLine's points with the size of the element)
The ViewModel:
public class ParticlePathVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    PointCollection points;
    public PointCollection Points { get => points; set { if (points != value) { points = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Points)); } } }

    Point startPoint;
    public Point StartPoint { get => startPoint; set { if (startPoint != value) { startPoint = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(StartPoint)); } } }

    double amplitude;
    public double Amplitude { get => amplitude; set { if (amplitude != value) { amplitude = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Amplitude)); UpdatePoints(); } } }

    public double AmplitudeMax { get; } = 10;

    public double Radius;
    public double Frequency;
    System.Threading.SynchronizationContext _context;

    public ParticlePathVM()
    {
        _context = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Radius = 266 - AmplitudeMax;
        StartPoint = new Point(Radius, 0);
        Amplitude = 5;
        Frequency = 10;
        UpdatePoints();
    }

    public void UpdateBounds(Size s)
    {
        if (s.Width > 1)
        {
            Radius = (s.Width / 2) - AmplitudeMax;
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} -> {1}", s, Radius));
            StartPoint = new Point(Radius, 0);
            UpdatePoints();
        }
    }

    void UpdatePoints()
    {
        var points = new List<Point>();
        for (float i = 0; i <= 360; i += 0.5F)
        {
            points.Add(GetCartesian(i));
        }
        _context.Post(o =>
        {
            Points = new PointCollection(points);
        }, null);

    }

    public Point GetCartesian(double angle)
    {
        var rad = angle * (Math.PI / 180.0);
        var r = Radius + Amplitude * Math.Sin(2 * Frequency * rad);
        return new Point(r * Math.Cos(rad), r * Math.Sin(rad));
    }
}

Again - when I change the amplitude from outside the VM, the shape of the circle does change, but the moving object does not change its path. It seems I need a way to update the storyboard and I'm not sure how to do that. Any suggestions?

Storyboards are always frozen by default when defined in styles or templates. That means their properties are no longer tracked for changes. You would have to create a new storyboard in code-behind. The context of that posted XAML is not obvious - that's why posting snippets is never useful, especially when you need help to identify an error... However, when you define the Storyboard as a resource it should be able to reference other resources e.g., a Path or PathGeometry using DynamicResource. This allows you to replace/update the Storyboard with the updated Path or PathGeometry.

The XAML contains everything in the associated UserControl - I just didn't want to show the full project name. But I'll look into Dynamic Resources and give that a try. Thanks!

As a note, it may be more efficient to use a MatrixTransform with a single MatrixAnimationUsingPath instead of a TranslateTransform with two DoubleAnimationUsingPath.

I tried the DynamicResource as suggested in the comments, but that didn't immediately work.
Since I'm defining the path in the code behind, I was able to simply bind the position of the TranslateTransform on my object to the VM and use the code representation of the path to move the object.
    <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Blue">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding PointX}" Y="{Binding PointY}"/>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>

And then
    double pointX;
    public double PointX { get => pointX; set { if (pointX != value) { pointX = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PointX)); } } }

    double pointY;
    public double PointY { get => pointY; set { if (pointY != value) { pointY = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PointY)); } } }
    double pointSpeed = 0.1;
    double pointAngle = 0;

    public void UpdatePoint(double ms)
    {
        pointAngle += (pointSpeed * (ms/1000));
        while(pointAngle > 360)
        {
            pointAngle -= 360;
        }
        var p = GetCartesian(pointAngle);
        PointX = p.X;
        PointY = p.Y;
    }

